# Strongswan site to site tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ipsec, strongswan, ikev2

I configured strongswan on ServerA and ServerB and tunnel them successfully by this tutorial:
http://linoxide.com/how-tos/ipsec-vpn-gateway-gateway-using-strongswan/
but i want to run this senario:

Client[IKEV2 VPN Connection] -----------> Server A ---[Strongswan Tunnel]-------> Server B -------> Internet access for client with Server B IP address

Servers have public IP and client should connect to server A ,then his traffic will be redirect from Server A to Server B and client will access to internet with Server B IP address.

Can anybody help me how can i do it?

Thanks